# Can we update several objects at one in an Entity Object?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

when **inserting** we just do

```
MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();

TableNameEntity o = new TableNameEntity();

o.Name = "me";
o.Age = 12;

db.TableNameEntity.AddObject(o); // Added

o = new TableNameEntity();

o.Name = "you";
o.Age = 23;

db.TableNameEntity.AddObject(o); // Added

db.SaveChanges(); // commits to db
```

Works fine.

But **how can I do** the same under an Update?

```
TableNameEntity o = db.TableNameEntity.Where(x=>x.id.Equals(tableId_1))
                           .FirstOrDefault();
o.Name = "myself";

o = db.TableNameEntity.Where(x=>x.id.Equals(tableId_2)).FirstOrDefault();
o.Name = "yourself";

db.SaveChanges(); // commits to db ..  Err!!!
```

there is no way to keep objects as well? so we just `SaveChanges` at the end?

---

What I'm after is to have a common place to place and hold the objects and only at the end, I commit all changes to the database.

currently in the Insert:

```
// Create 1nd Object
TableNameEntity o = new TableNameEntity();

// Don't Update the Database, just place it in the "basket"
db.TableNameEntity.AddObject(o);

// Create 2nd Object
o = new TableNameEntity();

// Don't Update the Database, just place it in the "basket"
db.TableNameEntity.AddObject(o);

// Now that I have all my objects done, let's commit all to the DB
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a form to do this but just **UPDATING** (so we can't use `AddObject`)

Comment: I don't see a problem in your update, what's the exception that you are getting?

Comment: I'm using the same object :o) that is a big problem, but I want to update all in at once, not one by one... just like when we are inserting.

Comment: What error are you getting?  And, as a matter of style, why are you using the same variable for two entirely different entities?

Comment: No it's not. Since the updated values are stored in the ObjectStateManager and that's what EF is looking at when it wants to generate Update statements. So it doesn't matter what you do with your local variable. What version are you using? 3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: @Morteza got it! The `ObjectStateManager` holds it as long it comes from it already. I was missing this HUGE step :) Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "as long as it comes from it already"? Can you please explain more?

Comment: when you fetch that object from the db, it will old not just all values but a "link" to that "Table Row", all you need is to change same values, and keep fetching, and keep changing. When done, just do a `db.SaveChanges()` and all modified objects will be updated, there is no need to "hold" anything, the EF "holds" it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Look here you can use [stub entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities) to update objects.  This will allow you to attach stubs and update or insert, then save the context.   [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities)

Note this will also save you the time of running Queries against the db to find the object to update.